# iterative 2-D regression dependent truncated normal/laplace distribution

Tags: python, random, distribution

I need your help in creating a normal or better **truncated** laplace distribution which linearly depends on another laplace distributed variable.

This is what I achieved so far unfortunately with NaNs in the derived y-distribution:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde, truncnorm

slope = 0.2237
intercept = 1.066
spread = 4.8719

def dependency(x):
    y_lin = slope * x + intercept
    lower = slope / spread * 3 * x
    upper = slope * spread / 3 * x + 2 * intercept

    y_lin_noise = np.random.laplace(loc=0, scale=spread, size=len(y_lin)) + y_lin

    y_lin_noise[y_lin_noise < lower] = np.nan  # This is the desperate solution where
    y_lin_noise[y_lin_noise > upper] = np.nan  # NaNs are introduced

    return y_lin_noise

max = 100
min = 1
mean = 40
sigma = 25

x = truncnorm((min-mean)/sigma, (max-mean)/sigma, loc=mean, scale=sigma).rvs(5000)
y = dependency(x)

# Plotting
xx = np.linspace(np.nanmin(x), np.nanmax(x), 100)
yy = slope * xx + intercept
lower = slope/spread*3*xx
upper = slope*spread/3*xx + 2*intercept

mask = ~np.isnan(y) & ~np.isnan(x)
x = x[mask]
y = y[mask]

xy = np.vstack([x, y])
z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)
idz = z.argsort()
x, y, z = x[idz], y[idz], z[idz]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.plot(xx, upper, 'r-.', label='upper constraint')
plt.plot(xx, lower, 'r--', label='lower constraint')

ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=3)
plt.xlabel(r'$\bf X_{laplace}$')
plt.ylabel(r'$\bf Y_{{derived}}$')
plt.plot(xx, yy, 'r', label='regression model')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Result]

What I want to get in the end is a y-distribution without NaNs, so that for every x there is a corresponding y within in the range of the upper/lower thresholds. So to say, a lower/upper-truncated distribution around the regression line.

I am looking forward to ideas!

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: You don't want to remove any value of x and y even though they could be out of bounds? Or is it acceptable to remove the outliers and make sure that every x you plot has a corresponding y within the bounds?

Comment: I'd prefer to constrain the prior creation of the laplace distribution to already lie inside the bounds and not have any NaNs in the final derived Y-distribution. My amateurish attempt might be confusing here.

Comment: Then you would want all noise to fall within the bounds? So you don't care that it no longer really is a laplace random distribution?

Comment: thats exactly what I need and you are right: I don't care if the data is not longer laplace or normal distributed but points should still have a higher frequency at the regression line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is basically retry for values that are outside your bounds. You could define a function that does this for every value or you could define the initial one and loop through the answer to "correct" the values that are out of bounds like this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde, truncnorm

slope = 0.2237
intercept = 1.066
spread = 4.8719


#slow but effective
def truncated_noise(y, lower, upper):
    while True:
        y_noise = np.random.laplace(loc=0, scale=spread, size=1) + y
        if upper > y_noise > lower:
            return y_noise


def refine_noise(y, y_lin_noise, lower, upper):
    for i in range(len(y_lin_noise)):
        if upper[i] < y_lin_noise[i] or lower[i] > y_lin_noise[i]:
            y_lin_noise[i] = truncated_noise(y[i], lower[i], upper[i])
    return y_lin_noise


def dependency(x):
    y_lin = slope * x + intercept
    lower = slope / spread * 3 * x
    upper = slope * spread / 3 * x + 2 * intercept

    y_lin_noise = np.random.laplace(loc=0, scale=spread, size=len(y_lin)) + y_lin

    y_lin_noise = refine_noise(y_lin, y_lin_noise, lower, upper)

    return y_lin_noise

max = 100
min = 1
mean = 40
sigma = 25

x = truncnorm((min-mean)/sigma, (max-mean)/sigma, loc=mean, scale=sigma).rvs(5000)
y = dependency(x)

# Plotting
xx = np.linspace(np.nanmin(x), np.nanmax(x), 100)
yy = slope * xx + intercept
lower = slope/spread*3*xx
upper = slope*spread/3*xx + 2*intercept


xy = np.vstack([x, y])
z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)
idz = z.argsort()
x, y, z = x[idz], y[idz], z[idz]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.plot(xx, upper, 'r-.', label='upper constraint')
plt.plot(xx, lower, 'r--', label='lower constraint')

ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=3)
plt.xlabel(r'$\bf X_{laplace}$')
plt.ylabel(r'$\bf Y_{{derived}}$')
plt.plot(xx, yy, 'r', label='regression model')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I don't know what you want to use this for but know that this is no longer a random laplace distribution so never do this if you need that for your function.

Comment: Nice it works! Thank you very much for this clever solution! Had some iterative solution in mind too but I didn't have an idea on how to realize it.

Comment: My initial answer passed through the y array with noise but it needed both for the correct implementation. So please use my latest edit ;) (If you didn't use the last one)